# date Ym adding +1 month

Tags: php, date

I need to add/substract +1/-1 month for a dynamic navigation. Here is what I've got so far - still struggling with the date-things: events.html?month=201401

```
<?php
$getdate=stripslashes((isset($_GET['month'])) ? $_GET ['month'] : "");
?>
<a href="events.html?month=<?php if($getdate=="")echo date('Ym',strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' +1 month')); else echo date('Ym',strtotime($getdate.' +1 month')); ?>">month +</a>
```

This should endup like these:

```
<november    actual    january>
```

Can anyone help out, please? Still got 201401 as href, which is correct for the first click. But it stays 201401 on second click and so on.

Comment: i have updated my answer. check now.

Comment: please remember to upvote the answer that suits you most

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```php
$month = isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('Ym');

$curr = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Ym', $month);
$prev = clone $curr; $prev->modify('-1 month');
$next = clone $curr; $next->modify('+1 month');

echo "PREV: " . $prev->format('F Y') . "\n";
echo "CURR: " . $curr->format('F Y') . "\n";
echo "NEXT: " . $next->format('F Y') . "\n";
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://eval.in/79940)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
$currentDate = !empty($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('Ym');
$currentTimespan = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($currentDate, 4, 2), 1, substr($currentDate, 0, 4));

$actual = date('Ym', $currentTimespan);
$previous = date('Ym', strtotime('-1 month', $currentTimespan));
$next = date('Ym', strtotime('+1 month', $currentTimespan));
```

Comment: Hey Carlos, sorry, there are still no updates on $next. next is 197002

Comment: fixed and tested... :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01'); // you can add you date here coming via $_GET['month']
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Ref : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the format you use (Ym) isn't recognised by the strtotime() function so you have to use the ATOM format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP") sub-string, or some other normalized format. ;)

```
<?php
$getdate = (strlen($_GET['month'])>0)?$_GET['month']:date('Y-m');
$month = date("Y-m", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($getdate)));
echo '<a href="sof_answer.php?month='.$month.'">month +</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple.
Add a month and then get only the month:

```
$time = new DateTime(); 
$time->modify('+1 month');
$month = $time->format('m'); 
print_r ($month);
```